# Compare DOM Elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

My task is very simple. I just want to compare two DOM Elements, like this:

HTML:

```
Are you a : Client <input id="client" name="cli_employ" type="radio" />
            Employer <input id="employ" name="cli_employ" type="radio" />
```

And my comparsion with jQuery:

```
$("input[name=cli_employ]").on("click", function() {
        // I'm sure my selector is working
        if ($(this) == $("#client")) { // How to compare?
            // do something
        }
        if ($(this) == $("#employ")) { // How to compare?
            // do something
        }
```

How can I compare  those elements with the 'if' command?
I just tried .is() and it always returns false.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this === $('#client')[0]

Comment: or just reference $(this).attr('id') === 'client'

Comment: or optionally have two different binding each binding on the separate ids, so you know what your dealing with in the first place

Comment: `I just tried .is() and it always returns false` So you are doing it wrong

Comment: $(this).attr('id') === 'client' solved my problem. Thank you all very much.

Comment: `is()` would work. Please show how you have used it.

Comment: $(this).is("#client") did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write:

```
if ($(this).attr('id') == 'client'))
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this way?

```
$("input[name=cli_employ]").on("click", function() {
    // I'm sure my selector is working
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "client") { // How to compare?
        // do something
    }
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "employ") { // How to compare?
        // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

*Code example*

```
if($(this).is("#client")){
   //Do something
}
```